# Quickfix acceptor validations

Tags: java, quickfixj

I have i server application using QuickFix/J.

how can QuickFix/j  validate host connecting to server?
don't want to use firewall to block ip's.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AllowedRemoteAddresses` setting. From the [documentation](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.3/usage/configuration.html), it is a "list of remote IP addresses which are allowed to connect to this acceptor".